# Probleme with height UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**This is my story:**

I have a problem with the size of my `IUTableViewCell`. When I add several cell, the cell auto resizing.

**any answer will be appreciated :)**

That my code to resize:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPathInCellTable:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*) [self tableView:tableView
                         cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGSize size;
    
    // SIZE HEIGHT TEXT
        size = [cell.color.text sizeWithAttributes:
                @{NSFontAttributeName:
                      [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]}];
    
      // SIZE HEIGHT FOR CELL
        CGRect frame = [cell frame];
        frame.size.height +=  size.height;
        [cell setFrame:frame];
    
      // SIZE HEIGHT IMG
        CGRect frame = [cell.img frame];
        frame.size.height = 69;
        frame.size.width = 69;
        [cell.img setFrame:frame];
        
    if (indexPath.row == 0) [self setHeightTableView:0];
    _tableHeightConstraint.constant += cell.frame.size.height;
    
    return cell.frame.size.height;
}
```

**There some screenshot :**

*the first time i add a cell everything is fine*

[image]

*the same for the second cell everything is fine*

[image]

*And there the problem comes*
[image]

Comment: pretty sure this is a duplicate; if I recall, it's bad to call `[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` inside `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPathInCellTable:` because iOS wants the height BEFORE it gets the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call CustomCell

```
 *cell = (CustomCell*) [self tableView:tableView
                         cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to get the a cell, which is wrong, because there is no cell created yet (so its nil). `tableView:heightForCell:atIndexPath:` get called before the cell was created. The best solution would be to have a module abject to save the height needed for your cell or make some similar calculations

Answer (score 0):

Use a prototype cell to get the sizing instead of using `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

http://www.samrayner.com/posts/dynamic-tableview-cells/